# How to create event button click in usercontrol into usercontrol on winform C#

Tags: winforms, events, user-controls

I got a problem with usercontrol like this:

- I have a formA contain 1 usercontrol with name UC_wrap
- and UC_wrap contain a usercontrol with name UC_child
- In UC_child contain : a button add, a button edit, a button delete and 1 textbox

but I don't know how do I create event for each button on formA?
please, Somebody help me !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rig UC_Wrap with an event that forwards any events it receives from the button to whoever is subscribed to it.

```
partial class UC_Wrap : Control
{
    public event EventHandler AddButtonClick
    {
        add { addButton.Click += value; }
        remove { addButton.Click -= value; }
    }
    // etc
}
```

Then the UC_Control can forward those events

```
partial class UC_Control : Control
{
    public event EventHandler AddButtonClickedInWrap
    {
        add { ucWrap.AddButtonClick += value; }
        remove { ucWrap.AddButtonClick -= value; }
    }
    // etc
}
```

Then finally at the FormA level you can subscribe to the event and handle it.

```
partial class FormA : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad() 
    {
        ucControl.AddButtonClickedInWrap += ActuallyDoSomething;
    }

    private void ActuallyDoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

That's probably the best way to do it. The only simpler way I can think of is to make each sub control public, but that has the major downside of exposing far more than is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//UC_child - child user control code

public event EventHandler addClick;
public event EventHandler editClick;
public event EventHandler deleteClick;

//call above event in each button click ie.
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (addClick != null)
         addClick(sender, e);
}
//Do same for other edit and delete button




//UC_wrap- UC_wrap usercontrol code
//Hand UC_Child event in UC_wrap
//Create event again in UC_wrap
public event EventHandler addClick;
public event EventHandler editClick;
public event EventHandler deleteClick;

private void UC_Child_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UC_Child1.addClick += new EventHandler(add_Click);
   //Do same for other edit and delete button
}

private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (addClick != null)
         addClick(sender, e);
}


//formA-This is your form code
private void formA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UC_wrap1.addClick += new EventHandler(add_Click);
   //Do same for other edit and delete button
}
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Place your code here.
}
```